# Html table out of card and container in print perview/Printing

Tags: html, printing

I am using bootstrap as style sheet for my html page. Page is absolutely fine . But when I see print perview then table is outside card. how to resolve this issue

First image is showing Html [First image is showing Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQxbx.jpg)
2nd image is showing pint perview [2nd image is showing pint perview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1yTe.jpg)